# A question on one dimensional random walk

Tags: probability-theory

At  $t=0$ a particle starts a random  from $x=0$ and takes a step t left or right with  equal probabilities $p=q=1/2$.What is the probability that eventually it will reach $x=1$ before it reaches $x=-5$?

Comment: This analysis is available in almost any book  that discusses random walks. If you don't understand a particular step in that analysis we can help.

Comment: could you please name one? or some hints?

Comment: It is  a good idea to read the section on Absorption Times and Absorption Probabilities  (Section 4 Chapter 3) of Markov Chains: theory and Applications by Isaacson and Madsen.